# How can I create Flutter numberpicker AlertDialog with more than 1 input?

Tags: flutter, dart, numberpicker, flutter-alertdialog

I know I can use [numberpicker](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker) pub.dev package to display an AlertDialog with one number wheel. How can I make an AlertDialog with more than one numberpicker?